# Button does not work on some mobile devices (eg iPhone6, Androids)

Tags: mobile, imagebutton, responsive-slides

this is my first question here and I was adviced to place this topic here.

I got a responsive website based on the AURA (PI-)theme. For the xs2 breakpoint I do show another slideshow on the homepage, where I have placed an  button as call to action (other button type didn't work either)

On older smartphones like iPhone4 and 5 it is working. But on newer device it ain't.

Please take a look onto this **[test-page](http://www.jungledaily.de/Daten/AG/web/)**.

You can also check within chrome browser emulating such a device. There the click on the "Explore"-button doesn't work either.

Any help is gladly welcome and I appriciate it very much.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to narrow it down to a codebase you could show us?

Comment: Sorry, I think it would be too much code to show. To norrow it down, it is a theme using the "Slider Revolution Responsive jQuery Plugin". You can look and inspect the source when hitting the test-page link.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You got a slideshow with a swipe handler which probably sets a preventDefault for swipe and click/tap. If I try to click it on a test device (android 4), it won't work either. But it does work if i hold it down and then press open. So it's not about the z-index (common error) but about the preventDefault. This means you would have to assign the link to the button/s in the slideshow with javascript.

EDIT:
To assign a link to an element using javascript (just javascript, no jquery or any other library), just put something like that into a script tag or javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("ID-of-your-button").addEventListener("click", function(){window.location.href = "http://link-desti.nation"});
```

and that should work fine. If there is another problem with it, just write a comment below please. I will reply on it as soon as possible.

P.S.: Sorry for the late edit, I was having hilariously much work on a "do immediately" level the last days.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. That helps to understand the problem. Can you explain more further what you mean with "assign the link to the button with javascript?"